# align an item to the right side of the View component?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile

How do I align the badge to the right?

[image]

This is the code that I currently have:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1}}>
  <Text style={{width: "20%"}}>Room:</Text>
  <Text>{this.props.title}</Text>
  <Badge value='(1/7)' style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end'}} />
</View>
```

Comment: did u try `justifyContent: 'flex-end'`

Comment: `margin-left:auto`? ie `<Badge value='(1/7)' style={{margin-left: 'auto'}} />`

Comment: margin-left: auto is giving a syntax error, and justifyContent is for parent containers, so that would justify the two text elements along with the badge

Comment: May bad sorry `<Badge value='(1/7)' style={{marginLeft: 'auto'}} />`. React camelCases kebab-case :)

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided your `View` isn't `display:flex`. If you change it and add marginLeft auto to your child it will align right.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, display: 'flex'}}>
    <Text style={{border: '1px solid green', width: "20%"}}>Room:</Text >
    <Text >{this.props.title}</Text >
    <Badge value='(1/7)' style={{border: '1px solid red', marginLeft: 'auto', width: '40px'}} />
</View>
```

OR you could force your middle node to fill the entire space between the two items.

```
  <View style={{border: '1px solid yellow', flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, display: 'flex', width: '100%'}}>
    <Text style={{border: '1px solid green', width: "20%"}}>Room:</Text >
    <Text style={{flex: 1}}>{this.props.title}</Text >
    <Badge value='(1/7)' style={{border: '1px solid red', width: '40px'}} />
  </View >
```

Example for you here https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-m-right-auto.

PS you could also `float:right` if you didn't want to use flex.

Comment: @haosmark I've updated with an additional example. If this doesn't work make sure the parent `View` is actually as wide as you presume it is. If it doesn't fill the screen it doesn't matter if the item is right aligned or not, it will never appear on the ride side of the screen :)